# Calculate Distinct Count in rolling 3 Days Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, distinct-values

I want to count unique customers over 3 days window grouped by city

input:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame([['1A', 'Cairo', '2020-12-01'],
                ["2A", 'Cairo', '2020-12-01'],
                ['1A', 'Cairo', '2020-12-02'],
                ['1A', 'Cairo', '2020-12-03'],
                ['3A', 'Alex', '2020-12-01'],
                ['3A', 'Alex', '2020-12-02'],
                ['3A', 'Alex', '2020-12-03'],
                ['4A', 'Giza', '2020-12-02'],
                ['4A', 'Giza', '2020-12-02'],
                ['5A', 'Giza', '2020-12-03'],
                ['6A', 'Giza', '2020-12-01']], columns=
    ['customer_id', 'city', 'day'])
```

expected output :

```
    output = pd.DataFrame([['Alex', '2020-12-01',1],
                ['Alex', '2020-12-02',1],
                ['Alex', '2020-12-03',1],
                ['Cairo', '2020-12-01',2],
                ['Cairo', '2020-12-02',2],
                ['Cairo', '2020-12-03',2],
                ['Giza', '2020-12-01',1],
                ['Giza', '2020-12-02',2],
                ['Giza', '2020-12-03',3]], columns=
    ['city', 'day', 'unique_customers_last3Days'])
```

I tried:

```
df['day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['day'])
df.set_index('day',inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
df.groupby('city').rolling("3D").agg({'customer_id':'nun'})
```

but it gives me error

```
AttributeError: 'nunique' is not a valid function for 'RollingGroupby' object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the index of dataframe to `day` then `sort` the index values, now `factorize` the `customer_id` column in order to assign unique codes to each of the customer id, then `group` the dataframe on `city` and `apply` a `rolling` `nunique` operation with window size of `3 days`. Optionally `drop` the duplicate values in `day` for each `city`

```
df = df.set_index('day').sort_index()
df['codes'] = df['customer_id'].factorize()[0]

df.groupby('city')\
  .rolling('3D')['codes'].apply(pd.Series.nunique)\
  .reset_index(name='unique').drop_duplicates(['city', 'day'], keep='last')
```

---

```
     city        day  unique
0    Alex 2020-12-01     1.0
1    Alex 2020-12-02     1.0
2    Alex 2020-12-03     1.0
4   Cairo 2020-12-01     2.0
5   Cairo 2020-12-02     2.0
6   Cairo 2020-12-03     2.0
7    Giza 2020-12-01     1.0
9    Giza 2020-12-02     2.0
10   Giza 2020-12-03     3.0
```

Comment: @SamehMostafa Does this answered your question?

Comment: Great! it works , thank you 
I just have one question, why did you make the factorization step ? is that because the IDs are not numbers? 
I mean If I have IDs as numbers should I do the factorization step?

Comment: Pandas `rolling` method works only on columns which have numerical data type, so in order to convert the `customer_id` to ordinal type we have used the `factorization` step. In case you already have the numbers in `ID`  column, you can definitely skip the factorization step.

Comment: Glad i could help!